# How do I replace all occurrences of certain characters with their predecessors?

Tags: perl, regex

```
$s = "bla..bla";
$s =~ s/([^%])\./$1/g;
```

I think it should replace all occurrences of `.` that is not after `%` with the character that is before `.`.

But `$s` is then: `bla.bla`, but
 it should be `blabla`. Where is the problem? I know I can use quantifiers, but I need do it this way.

Comment: Which output you expect?

Comment: i am expecting blabla

Comment: Actually, no you don't (need to do it this way). Since a literal dot is not a percent, we all ready know that any stream of dots preceded by a character that is not a percent can we wiped out. If it so happens that we have '%...', then the re engine will gladly preserve the dot following the percent, counting it as a non-percent character preceding a string of dots, and delete the rest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a global regular expression is searching a string it will not find overlapping matches.

The first match in your string will be `a.`, which is replaced with `a`.  When the regex engine resumes searching it starts at the next `.` so it sees `.bla` as the rest of the string, and your regex requires a character to match before the `.` so it cannot match again.

Instead, use a negative lookbehind to perform the assertion that the previous character is not `%`:

```
$s =~ s/(?<!%)\.//g;
```

Note that if you use a positive lookbehind like `(?<=[^%])`, you will not replace the `.` if it is the first character in the string.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that even with the `/g` flag, each substitution starts looking where the previous one left off. You're trying to replace `a.` with `a` and then `a.` with `a`, but the second replacement doesn't happen because the `a` has already been "swallowed" by the previous replacement.

One fix is to use a [zero-width lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$s =~ s/(?<=[^%])\.//g;
```

which will remove any `.` that is *not* the first character in the string, and that is *not* preceded by `%`.

But you might actually want this:

```
$s =~ s/(?<!%)\.//g;
```

which will remove any `.` that is *not* preceded by `%`, even if it *is* the first character in the string.

Answer (score 4):

Much simpler than look-behinds is to use:

```
$s =~ s/([^%])\.+/$1/g;
```

This replaces any string of one or more dots after a character other than `%` by nothing.

Comment: I don't think that regex does what you think it does.  May I recommend a backslash before that dot?

Comment: +1 for removing the overlap problem. Remember, `\K` and you don't have to "carry the ($)1". `s/[^%]\K\.+//g`. (Since 5.10!)

Comment: @Axeman: Remember `\K`?  No; I'll have to learn what `\K` means...  It wasn't in Perl 4, was it?  :D